# how to input large amounts of data into a query parameter via REST Assured

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured

I have an API that returns a list of ~30,000 SKUs. I then need to insert each SKU into the query parameter URL of another API to validate the response of this second API.
I know that something like this is possible with Jmeter where you could possibly do this via a CSV file. How can I accomplish this via REST Assured? An example/sample would be greatly appreciated!

Similar question also applies to using outputs from an API to use as input in body content...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer.You can't as it comes to query parameters. You can have no more than 2000 characters in your URL. Explanation here : [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

With respect of POST method you don't have constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to evaluating alternatives to REST-assured, [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) allows you to easily achieve such a data-driven test and it is based on Cucumber as well.

Disclaimer: I am the dev.

In the [demos](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo) you will find a number of examples that use dynamic JSON data to drive a loop making an HTTP call. Yes, you can dynamically use the data in HTTP responses also in future steps.

Comment: Can you provide me with the example of a code snippet for this exact scenario, using Karate?
Thanks

Comment: @Styris there are plenty in the demos. Take a look at this specific line (29): https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/calldynamic/call-dynamic-json.feature#L29